# Polar to cartesian form of $r=\cos(4θ)$?

Tags: polar-coordinates

> Consider an equation in polar coordinates, $r = \cos(4θ)$. Find the equation of the curve in the first quadrant in Cartesian coordinates.

This is for an assignment and this is what help I have received so far from user170231-

$$\begin{align}
r(\theta)&=\cos(4\theta)\\[1ex]
&=\cos^4\theta-6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta\\[1ex]
&=\frac{r^4\left(\cos^4\theta-6\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta+\sin^4\theta\right)}{r^4}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{(r\cos \theta)^4-6(r\cos \theta)^2(r\sin \theta)^2+(r\sin \theta)^4}{\left(r^2\right)^2}
\end{align}$$

He told me to see if I could solve it now, and here's what I could come up with:

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Is this step correct? If so, am I done with the transformation of $r=\cos(4θ)$ to cartesian for the **first quadrant only**? If not, where should I go from here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd say so, remember that since you only care about the first quadrant that $x,y\ge 0$

Comment: Hi, Welcome to MSE! Note that $r=cos(4\theta)$ is positive and negative, so $r=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: so do I put absolute value signs around $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and I will be done with the transformation?

Comment: you have an extra solution with LHS $= -\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ so you have to solve for both $+$ and $-$

Comment: so for a first quadrant solution, I would still need a ± in front of $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? If so, does adding the ± really make a difference?

Comment: If you plot the graph it is symmetric is all quadrants, it looks like an 8 petalled flower, if you only solve for $+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ you only get 4 petals

Comment: ok got that. Now, how do I limit the graph to just the first quadrant?

Comment: why not $x,y \geq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! Here you can see how $r=cos(4\theta)$ is negative and positive and the importance of solving for both $\pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I got the importance. But now, I want to limit it to the first quadrant. How do I do that because that is what the question is asking.

Comment: I think you can just say $x,y \geq 0$ as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: ok i see. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad to help